# ckEditor not saving link in IE

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I have a strang bug(?) with ckeditor; a project, I work with, has ckEditor as texteditor and works fine, except on IE, where, when hyperlink option is chose, it has some extra fields:

[image]

The "Select an Anchor" and the "Email" parts are visible only in IE and are preventing(?) for the link to be created ( save and cancel buttons not working ).

Now, I was wondering, where can I disable them? Are they custom settings or is this an IE thing?

Comment: I believe these questions should be asked to CKEDITOR's support here https://dev.ckeditor.com/wiki/Bugs

Comment: @Eric I don't think that's a bug. I think that someone just messed with ckeditor settings, but I can't find where, since I don't have much experiance with this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a custom extension/replacement of the default CKEditor [Link plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/link). If you open the [demo on CKEditor site](http://ckeditor.com/demo), the Link dialog window does not include the "Insert crosslink" button. Most of the fields that you are seeing should also only display for a particular Link Type (anchor, e-mail). Looks like someone messed with the dialog.

Check your editor version (and upgrade to the latest one which is always a good idea); check what you are using as the Link plugin replacement and either fix it or just use the official one.